# How to convert data structure with DFs inside a Dict to one large DF w/ keys as rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

As per the title, I have a data structure with a dict with a key and DF inside as the value. e.g. {key}:DF w/30 columns. There are ~500 key: DF pairs.

How can I convert the data to one big data frame where the key would be repeated for each row in the DF? e.g:

```
key1 | row 1 vals
key1 | row 2 vals
key2 | row 1 vals
key2 | row 2 vals
```